# How can I increase the 1000000 limit of output in Maple?

Tags: sequences-and-series, maple

Please is it possible to increase the 1000000 maximum limit of output? I tried doing some computation in form of power series for larger series but I got the message "1000000 limit of output exceeced". How can I resolve this?

Comment: This question is basically for computer science, try to save you results in a file then you do not have restriction of size.

Comment: Is it possible to write the Maple code that made this error?

Comment: @SaeidAli No, that's no computer science. This is a question about [Software that mathematicians use](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and therefore on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

In Maple, the limit for the size of output is controlled in the precision tab of the Options menu. To change this, go to **Tools - Options - Precision - Limit Expression Length to** ##### precision setting and update the value accordingly.